# Are 2nd conditional and Mixed Conditional(Past condition/present result) interchangeable?

Tags: conditionals

Here is 2nd conditional - present or future situations that are impossible or unlikely in reality:

*If I won a lot of money, I'd buy a big house in the country.*

And Mixed Conditional(Past condition/present result) - past change with a result in the present:

*If she had tried harder, she would be more successful now.*

Both look like to carry the same purpose like regretting of the past and imaginable unreal present or I miss some slight difference? Will it be mistake if we use Mixed Conditional(Past condition/present result) instead of 2nd conditional and and vice versa?

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical and use appropriate verb constructions in each of the two clauses to convey clearly what the speaker wishes to convey. Can you explain what the question in the last sentence of your post is asking?

Comment: If I say
"If she had tried harder, she would be more successful now" (Mixed Conditional: Past condition/present result)
or
"If she tried harder, she would be more successful now" (2nd Conditional)
does the meaning stay absolutely the same?

Comment: No, they don't mean the same. "_If she had tried harder, she would be more successful now_" (this is a counterfactual -  she didn't try hard, so she is not successful now) - "_If she tried harder, she would be more successful_" (she will be successful if she now starts to try harder. The 2nd conditional here expresses a certain doubt that she will in fact try harder.)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, you clearly understand the difference between your two sentences, so you can understand why it's wrong to use each form with the other. To extend your examples:

- If she tried harder, she would be more successful.
  [You can say this about her now, while she is still trying, but not when the story is over.]
- If I had won a lot of money, I'd have bought a big house in the country.
  [That's your past history. You can't say this, if you are talking about your current life.]